# Не работает плавный переход по якорной ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Есть проблема с плавностью перехода по якорной ссылке. Сам переход к нужному блоку работает, только нет плавности. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде. Якорная ссылка - белый кружок под именем.

```js
$(function() {
  var link = $('a[data-toggle="modal"]');
  link.on('click', function(event) {
    var work = $(this).attr('data-work');
    var modal = $('.modal');
    modal.find('.modal-body').load(work + '.html');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

a:active,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000 url(../img/main-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}

.main-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
}

.main p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-down {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
  bottom: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  line-height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.main-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}


/* Секция с портфолио */

.portfolio {
  padding: 10rem 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.portfolio img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
}

.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem auto 6rem;
  color: #333;
  width: 17rem;
}

.portfolio a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Секция - подвал (footer) */

.footer {
  background-color: #646464;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.footer strong {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.social-links {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.social-links a {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.social-links a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #646464;
}

.offer-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.offer-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #646464;
}

.modal img {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-title {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.modal-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-btn:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  html {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
  .footer strong {
    margin-top: 3rem 0 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .social-links a {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .footer strong {
    margin-top: 3rem 0 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-overlay"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-header">
      <h1>Кази Рустамов</h1>
      <div class="main-line"></div>
      <p>Верстка на HTML и CSS <br> Разработка сайтов под ключ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="main-down" href="#portfolio"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section-header">Портфолио</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="portfolio-block">
          <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Работа №1">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-1' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="portfolio-block">
          <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Работа №2">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-2' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="portfolio-block">
          <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Работа №3">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-3' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <strong>Кази Рустамов</strong>
        <p>Разработка сайтов <br> под ключ</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <strong>Подпишитесь</strong>
        <div class="social-links">
          <a href="https://vk.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-vk"></i></a>
          <a href="https://instagram.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <strong>Напишите мне</strong>
        <a href="https://vk.me/rustamov_17" target="_blank" class="offer-btn">Заказать сайт</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: код надо скопировать в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо добавить `id` и `name` к `div`

```
<div class="portfolio" name="portfolio" id="portfolio">
```

И скрипт, который делает анимацию:

```
$('a.main-down').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();      
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);   
});
```

```js
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" > </script> 
<script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
      var link = $('a[data-toggle="modal"]');
    link.on('click', function(event) {
      var work = $(this).attr('data-work');
      var modal = $('.modal');

      modal.find('.modal-body').load(work + '.html');
    });
    $('a.main-down').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
  
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);

    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

a:active,
a:visited,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000 url(../img/main-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}

.main-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
}

.main p {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.main-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-down {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 4;
  bottom: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  line-height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.main-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}


/* Секция с портфолио */

.portfolio {
  padding: 10rem 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.portfolio img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
}

.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem auto 6rem;
  color: #333;
  width: 17rem;
}

.portfolio a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Секция - подвал (footer) */

.footer {
  background-color: #646464;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.footer strong {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.social-links {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.social-links a {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.social-links a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #646464;
}

.offer-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.offer-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #646464;
}

.modal img {
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-title {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 1rem;
}

.modal-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-btn:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  html {
    font-size: 7px;
  }
  .footer strong {
    margin-top: 3rem 0 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .social-links a {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .footer strong {
    margin-top: 3rem 0 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- meta для социальных сетей -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Кази Рустамов - верстка сайтов на HTML и CSS">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Закажите разработку сайта без посредников от 5 990 рублей">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Портфолио верстальщика">
  <meta property="article:author" content="Кази Рустамов">
  <!-- Заголовок сайта -->
  <title>Кази Рустамов - Портфолио</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello-embedded.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Фавиконка -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="main-header">
        <h1>Кази Рустамов</h1>
        <div class="main-line"></div>
        <p>Верстка на HTML и CSS <br> Разработка сайтов под ключ</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="main-down" href="#portfolio"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="portfolio" name="portfolio" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="section-header">Портфолио</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Работа №1">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-1' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Работа №2">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-2' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="portfolio-block">
            <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Работа №3">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-3' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <strong>Кази Рустамов</strong>
          <p>Разработка сайтов <br> под ключ</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <strong>Подпишитесь</strong>
          <div class="social-links">
            <a href="https://vk.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-vk"></i></a>
            <a href="https://instagram.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/rustamov_17" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <strong>Напишите мне</strong>
          <a href="https://vk.me/rustamov_17" target="_blank" class="offer-btn">Заказать сайт</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: А ты скрипт анимации полностью написал? Просто я его вставил - не работает.

Comment: @КазиРустамов попробуйте полностью скопировать скрипт из примера (вместе с $(document).ready) и вставить его себе.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо Вам большое!